# Preferential break on float attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project, and I need know how I can force breakline, giving preference to a float:right element.

See this picture:

[image]
There are some CSS attribute that I can use to work with this case? I have tried `clear: left`, but nothing.

**Code**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9UAR/)

**Out of script**: what you think that have a better visual? `:p`

Comment: Could you add your current HTML/CSS?

Comment: You should post the code, preferably a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to move your element with `float: right` to before your other elements:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/G9UAR/1/

```
<div class="message">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./User/options/Language">Alterar preferências de idioma</a></li>
        <li><a href="./User/options/Language">Alterar preferências de idioma</a></li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Informação:</strong>
    <span>A página não está disponível em seu idioma. O inglês está sendo usado.</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

It is (probably) possible to do without switching around the HTML, but that answer would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Make sure you test it at different `width`s and that you're happy with the way the text wraps. If so, then good :)